# Can I use JPQL to query a MySQL database which was populated by loading CSV files?

Tags: java, mysql, jpql

This is something of a noob question, so please bear with me.

I'm building a Java web app which is deployed on JBoss.  Part of the functionality is populating a MySQL DB with data from an Excel spreadsheet.  This can be achieved in 2 ways:

1. Using JExcel / Apache POI to parse the spreadsheet data and creating Entity "beans" which are then  persisted to the DB.
2. Using scripts to convert the spreadsheet to csv files and then load the csv files into the DB.

My question is:  If I choose the scripting / csv route, can I still use JPQL to query the DB or will I have to resort to native SQL queries in the Java code?

Answer (score 0):

JPQL can be used to query table independently from method that was used to populate table. Data stored to table is not aware of with which method it was inserted.

JPA is not notified about changes made to data via script, but in typical use case with no additional caches and transaction-scoped [PersistenceContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType.html) that is not the issue, because query will hit the database and deliver fresh data.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mikko.  So will I need to specify Java Entity classes in order to query the DB via JPQL?  I hope this makes sense.  Like I said, I'm just beginning with this.

Comment: Yes, JPQL queries operate to entities and their attributes and that's why it cannot be used without them.

Comment: Thank you once again Mikko.